# Firebase observeSingleEvent continuously duplicate entry being appended in my array

Tags: swift

When I refresh the collection view the data duplicates by +1 in my. How can I avoid duplicate entries in my array when I pull to refresh this function?
Also used self.posts.removeAll() still no result.

```
var posts = [Post]() {
    didSet {
        collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}

var following = [String]()
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.gray
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fetchPosts), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    collectionView?.addSubview(refreshControl)
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    fetchPosts()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}

func fetchPosts(){
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        guard let users = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] else {
            return
        }
        print(snapshot.key)
        for (_,value) in users {
            if let uid = value["uid"] as? String {
                if uid == FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
                    if let followingUsers = value["following"] as? [String : String]{
                        for (_,user) in followingUsers{
                            self.following.append(user)
                            print(user)
                        }
                    }
                    self.following.append(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)

                    ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                        for postSnapshot in snap.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                        let post = postSnapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
                        print(snap.key)

                            if let userID = post["userID"] as? String {
                                for each in self.following {
                                    if each == userID {
                                        print(each)
                                        let posst = Post()

                                        if let date = post["date"] as? Int, let author = post["author"] as? String, let likes = post["likes"] as? Int, let pathToImage = post["pathToImage"] as? String, let postID = post["postID"] as? String {

                                            posst.date = Int(date)
                                            posst.author = author
                                            posst.likes = likes
                                            posst.pathToImage = pathToImage
                                            posst.postID = postID
                                            posst.userID = userID

                                            print(posst)
                                            if let people = post["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                                for (_,person) in people {
                                                    posst.peopleWhoLike.append(person as! String)
                                                }
                                            }


                                            var postExist:Bool = false
                                            for post in self.posts {
                                                if post.postID == posst.postID {
                                                    postExist = true
                                                    break
                                                }
                                            }

                                            if !postExist {
                                                self.posts.append(posst)
                                            }

                                            self.posts.sort(by: {$0.date! > $1.date!})
                                            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }

    })
    ref.removeAllObservers()
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PostCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! PostCell

    cell.posts = posts[indexPath.row]

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    for person in post.peopleWhoLike {
        if person == FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid {
            cell.like.isHidden = true
            cell.unlike.isHidden = false
            break
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

}

Updated with the solutions.

Comment: Could sort it with date like this self.posts.sort(by: {$0.date! > $1.date!}) after appending the data into an array. But still need help to avoid duplicates when I scroll to reload the collection view. Thanks

Comment: If my answer below doesn't solve your problem, you need to upload your whole view controller, because some of your code is missing for this to make complete sense.

Comment: Added the complete code. Thanks

Comment: Can you add some data from your database to your question, so I can test it.

Answer (score 2):

I take it that when the refresh is activated, this function is called and that all the posts are downloaded. For your duplicate problem, it seems that you keep on appending data to your posts array without removing the old data.

```
ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in

    let postsSnap = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]

    self.posts.removeAll() // This will remove previously downloaded posts.

    // All your other code ...
```